# Locking/Logging-off Windows 10 after a set period of time

Tags: windows-10, logout

I would like to be able to lock (or alternately log off) a user in windows 10 after a period of time so that I can keep closer control of my children's computer usage.

I have tried using `shutdown.exe /l /t 3600` but the /l and /t options don't seem to work together.

**Note:** I have searched for a solution to this and all I can find are thousands of sites talking about shutting down after a period of inactivity. That is not what I want, I am looking for it to shut down after a period of time regardless of if there is activity.

Comment: Windows 10 has built-in Parental Controls, that are far more effective, then a scheduled task that can be disabled by a non-privileged user.  Why are you not using those built-in parental control capabilities?

Comment: Because the parental control features require the use of Microsoft accounts and for other reasons, i am using local accounts

Comment: You will then have to use third-party parental control software, Windows does not have a feature that will logout a user after a period of time.  Third-party Kiosk software could be a potential solution.